# ms sql server group by max

Tags: sql-server, group-by

The table `InterfaceTraffic_detail` (from Solarwinds SQL Server) basically has a table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InterfaceTraffic_Detail](
    [InterfaceID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [In_Maxbps] [real] NULL,
    [Out_Maxbps] [real] NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_InterfaceTraffic_Detail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InterfaceID] ASC,
    [DateTime] ASC,
    [Archive] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Data:

```
InterfaceID  Out_Maxbps  In_Maxbps    DateTime
------------|-----------|------------|-------------------------|
1           | 10        | 10         | 2015-06-23 01:03
1           | 11        | 11         | 2015-06-23 01:08
2           | 12        | 12         | 2015-06-23 01:05
2           | 10        | 10         | 2015-06-23 01:10
```

How can I `group by` `InterfaceID`?

```
select 
     max(Out_Maxbps) over (partition by itt.InterfaceID),
     avg(Out_Maxbps) over (partition by itt.InterfaceID),
     max(In_Maxbps) over (partition by itt.InterfaceID),
     avg(In_Maxbps) over (partition by itt.InterfaceID),
     itt.InterfaceID, 
     itt.datetime
from InterfaceTraffic_detail as itt with (nolock)
where (itt.DateTime >= '2015-06-23 01:00:00'
     and itt.DateTime <= '2015-06-23 05:00:00'
     and (itt.InterfaceID = 489108 or itt.InterfaceID = 489109 or itt.InterfaceID = 1220996))
group by itt.InterfaceID
order by itt.InterfaceID asc;
```

I keep getting error:

> Column 'InterfaceTraffic_detail.Out_Maxbps' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What is your expected result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap it in a CTE and use `ROW_NUMBER` to take only one row per group:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    select 
         MaxOutBPS = max(Out_Maxbps) over (partition by itt.InterfaceID),
         AvgOutBPS = avg(Out_Maxbps) over (partition by itt.InterfaceID),
         MaxInBPS =  max(In_Maxbps) over (partition by itt.InterfaceID),
         AvgInBPS = avg(In_Maxbps) over (partition by itt.InterfaceID),
         itt.InterfaceID, 
         itt.datetime,
         RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itt.InterfaceID ORDER BY itt.InterfaceID asc)
    from InterfaceTraffic_detail as itt with (nolock)
    where (itt.DateTime >= '2015-06-23 01:00:00'
         and itt.DateTime <= '2015-06-23 05:00:00'
         and (itt.InterfaceID = 489108 or itt.InterfaceID = 489109 or itt.InterfaceID = 1220996))
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
order by InterfaceID asc;
```

Comment: You rock :) that was so quick and so helpful

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the query works no problem.  There was quite a few small errors that probably came from typing it up rather than the query.

You will be unable to group anything while your including the datetime field.

```
select 
     max(Out_Maxbps),
     avg(Out_Maxbps),
     max(In_Maxbps),
     avg(In_Maxbps),
     InterfaceID
from InterfaceTraffic_detail 
group by InterfaceID
```

Comment: You missed the column `itt.datetime`

Comment: Sure I did, for the reason I mentioned.  I ran the CTE version and it worked, but I don't see why its necessary.  You either want the last date time or first, so Min or Max will work just the same on that field as it did on the others?